# QPropertyAnimation not functioning

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qpropertyanimation

My animation isn't working on this QPushButton quite the way I'm expecting.

Here's my mainwindow.cpp, as you can see nothing particularly weird here. On runtime the button appears as one might expect. I didn't have any particular movement in mind. I just wanted to see if I had set everything up correctly. As things are right now the button doesn't grow or move. What's strange here is that if I comment out the setShape.start() it defaults back to the size designated in the UI file.

My only guess thus far is that my MainWindow object isn't being displayed until after its constructor (containing the animation) has run its course. If this is the case, I'm wondering what I can do to get around it.

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QLabel>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QPropertyAnimation>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QPropertyAnimation setShape(ui->pushButton, "geometry");
    setShape.setDuration(1000);
    setShape.setStartValue(QRect(500,300,500,500));
    setShape.setEndValue(QRect(800,400,500,500));
    setShape.start();


}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Here's my main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPropertyAnimation>
#include <QPushButton>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

This is about as basic an animation as one could create, so I'm hoping that either my intuition on this is correct, or I'm making a silly mistake. Either way any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: show your .ui..

Comment: Have you used any layout?

Comment: I have not used any layouts for formatting. Imagine you just made a default Qt application- that's basically what I'm working with here.

Comment: Also, eyllanesc- what do you mean by show the ui?

Comment: I was referring to the design file that has extension .ui, anyway according to what you mention is not necessary, try my proposed solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A local variable is deleted after it finishes executing its scope, and that is what happens with setShape, it is eliminated when the constructor finishes executing, what you have to do is create a pointer so that it is maintained and establish the policy of destruction to `DeleteWhenStopped`:

```
QPropertyAnimation *setShape = new QPropertyAnimation(ui->pushButton, "geometry");
setShape->setDuration(1000);
setShape->setStartValue(QRect(500,300,500,500));
setShape->setEndValue(QRect(800,400,500,500));
setShape->start(QPropertyAnimation::DeleteWhenStopped);
```

Comment: Okay, maybe not actually. Thought it worked but it still isn't moving. My apologies.

Comment: @Carl It works for me correctly, you could share the mainwindow.ui

Comment: @Carl Are you sure, have you added any component? I find it very strange

Comment: On that note, I did get it to work just now. I just stuck a QPropertyAnimation pointer inside my MainWindowClass. This stops the object from being destroyed as the program leaves its scope.

Comment: @Carl It's the same thing that I just proposed, in both cases it should work

Comment: I'm going to accept your answer anyway since you were right about the core issue. I'll give your solution another shot since its a lot more elegant than mine.